# Botón para cambiar texto y regresar al anterior

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, botón

Necesito su ayuda para poner un botón que haga que cambie un texto dentro de un `div` y que vuelva el mismo contenido pulsando ese mismo botón, o poner otro botón al lado

**Opción 1 (1 solo botón)**

- El `div` tiene un contenido (Llamémosle contenido 1)
- al pulsar "Botón1" el contenido cambia a "Contenido 2" y el botón cambia 
  su nombre.
- Al volver a pulsar "Botón 1" el contenido vuelve al "contenido 1" y el 
  botón vuelve a su nombre de origen.

**Opción 2: (2 botones)**

- El `div` tiene un contenido (Llamémosle contenido 1)
- Al pulsar "Botón 1" el contenido cambia a "Contenido 2"
- Al pulsar "Botón 2" el contenido vuelve al "contenido 1"

Ya lo he intentado con `javascript` pero solo logro que aparezca el nuevo texto sin regreso al anterior y los botones nunca cambian su texto. La web está basada en `Bootstrap` por lo que uso sus botones diseñados.

Les agradezco de antemano su colaboración!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código con el que has intentado. Pásate por la sección [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hola te paso las funciones de `javascript` para las 2 opciones:

**Opción 1 (1 solo botón)**

```js
function cambiar(){
  let contenedor=document.getElementById("contenedor");
  let boton=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  if (boton[0].innerText=='Ver 2'){
    contenedor.innerText='Contenido 2';
    boton[0].innerText='Ver 1'
  } else {
    contenedor.innerText='Contenido 1';
    boton[0].innerText='Ver 2'    
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">Contenido 1</div>
<button onclick="cambiar()">Ver 2</button>
```

**Opción 2: (2 botones)**

```js
function ver1(e){
  let contenedor=document.getElementById("contenedor");
  if (e==1){
    contenedor.innerText='Contenido 1';
  } else if (e==2){
    contenedor.innerText='Contenido 2';    
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">Contenido 1</div>
<button onclick="ver1(1)">Ver 1</button>
<button onclick="ver1(2)">Ver 2</button>
```

Espero que te sirva